# how do I generate set of all tokens of length exactly equal to 8

Tags: c, algorithm, combinations

I need to generate complete set of tokens of size exactly equal to 8.Each bit in the token can assume values from `0 - 9` and `A -Z`. For example-

The following are valid tokens:
00000000
0000000A
000000H1
Z00000XA

So basically i want to generate all tokens from 00000000 to ZZZZZZZZ.
How do i do this in C

Comment: Write a nested loop.  Post that code if you get stuck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort before asking the community for help.

Comment: also 36^8 is a lot of strings

Comment: Of course  with a nested loop but how many loops do I need? eight loops?

Comment: @user4964911 8 loops or 1 recursive function

Comment: Removing `[java]` and `[C++]` as the question asks to do this in C.

Comment: You can use nested loops or recursion.  Either way it won't complete in a day.

Comment: Careful! That is almost 3 trillion combinations. If you write them as text, you'll need over 20 terabytes to store them. Long story short: You don't want to do that in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You caught me on a day where I don't want to do what I'm supposed to be doing<sup>1</sup>.

The code below only generates token output; it doesn't attempt to store tokens anywhere.  You can redirect the output to a file, but as others have pointed out, you're going to need a bigger <strike>boat</strike> hard drive to store 36<sup>8</sup> strings.  There's probably a way to do this without the nested loops, but this method is pretty straightforward.  The first loop updates the counter in each position, while the second maps the counter to a symbol and writes the symbol to standard output.

You can set `LEN` to a smaller value like 3 to verify that the program does what you want without generating terabytes of output. Alternately, you could use a smaller set of characters for your digits.  Ideally, both `LEN` and `digs` should be command-line parameters rather than constants, but I've already spent too much time on this.

**Edit**

Okay, I lied.  Apparently I haven't spent too much time on this, because I've cleaned up a minor bug (the first string isn't displayed correctly because I was doing the update before the display) and I've made the length and character set command-line inputs.

Note that this code assumes C99.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEFAULT_LEN 8

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  const char *default_digs="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  size_t len = DEFAULT_LEN;
  const char *digs = default_digs;

  if ( argc > 2 )
    digs = argv[2];

  if ( argc > 1 )
    len = strtoul( argv[1], NULL, 10 );

  int idx[len];
  memset( idx, 0, sizeof idx );

  size_t diglen = strlen( digs );

  for(;;)
  {
    int j = len;
    while( j )
      putchar( digs[idx[--j]] );

    putchar( '\n' );

    while ( j < len && idx[j] == diglen - 1 )
      idx[j++] = 0;

    if ( j == len )
      break;

    idx[j]++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/tokgen: ./tokgen 2 01
00
01
10
11

[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/tokgen: ./tokgen 3 01
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111

[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/tokgen: ./tokgen 2 012
00
01
02
10
11
12
20
21
22
```

---

<sup>1.  Which, to be fair, is pretty much any day ending in a 'y'.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion or a nested loop here at all.

You just need a counter from 0 through 36<sup>8</sup>-1, followed by converting the results to an output in base 36.

That said, 36<sup>8</sup> strings, each with a length of 8 bytes is 22,568,879,259,648 bytes, or approximately 20.5 terabytes of data.

Assuming a sustained rate of 100 megabytes per second, it'll take approximately 63 hours to write all that data to some hard drives.